# My colleague uses slang around the office and it offends me. Can I do something?

Tags: professionalism, behavior

I have worked with this colleague for about 6 months. He can act professional when he wants to but he usually likes to use such phrases like "aight man" when saying good bye or says "for sho" when saying yes. Granted this talk from people outside of work never bothered me before I started working here. It bothers me because I like to imagine my office place as a educated professional environment that I can take pride in. For someone to lower the standard by partaking in forced slang that is reserved for the club or the block offends me. Presently I do not think anyone else notices his speech and I do not think anyone else will do anything about it. He is newer at the company and about 10 years younger than me. Is there a way I can politely ask him to "leave it at the door" or do I just have to put up with it? If I did not work with him and I knew him as a friend outside the office I would have told him to knock it off because it makes him sound stupid.

Comment: How does the slang affect his ability to perform his job? If it doesn't, look in the mirror.

Comment: "For someone to lower the standard by partaking in forced slang that is reserved for the club or the block offends me. " You say this and you're the one that's offended?

Comment: I know my complaint is unusual but not unreasonable. I imagine people would feel offended if someone had a habit of using offensive language during their church service so what is the difference if it is in the workplace. This might be a situation where I just need to try and not worry about how someone else behaves.

Comment: @user1740117 It's actually the opposite.  Your complaint is not unusual, but it is unreasonable.  And I have a hard time rationalizing how you feel that "fo' sho'" is in any way close to "offensive language".

Comment: OP, does your colleague calling you "man" bother you? You mention the age difference, which seems to suggest you would prefer he be more professional with you - is that correct?

Comment: I had a similar encounter once and replied to them with similar slang (a London vsriant) - perfectly understandable if you know and acted surprised when they had issue... They changed their behaviour quickly :)

Comment: People can talk however they want as long as they are being respectful. Being offended by something as "fo sho" is like being offended by an accent. Stop being butthurt over simple stuff and work on yourself to be less triggerable.

Comment: Besides, he can act professional when he wants to, but he doesn't "act" professional with you. He's being normal around you. It means he trusts you, and he's being more open, kind and sincere with you, and sees you as a collegue, not as a superior. He wants to create a friendly atmosphere so he can feel comfortable working with you. That's more professional than anything you're doing to pretend that you're working in "an educated professional environment". You should probably learn from him...

Answer (score 8):

I think you answered your own question:

> He can act professional when he wants to

Operative word there is **act**.  He can **act** professional when he wants to.  It's an **act**.  That's not how he is naturally or normally.  And you're asking him to, in addition to doing his normal duties, to **act** in a way that he normally doesn't, and pay attention to that.

People are the way they are.  He's not asking you to not **act** like someone who is not stuck-up and worries about things that don't matter like how someone talks (using the same definition of "act" as above; clearly you are that type of person and not worrying about them would be an act), so don't ask him to **act** in some way that is counter to his nature either.

Put another way, for many people, yourself obviously not included, but myself definitely included, a social atmosphere is good at work.  If you can hang out and be friends with your coworkers, then when it comes to work you're helping out your friends, you're not helping out some faceless entity that gives you a paycheque.  It's a morale booster.  And clearly your company has that type of atmosphere where your colleague feels like he can act in this way, and, because you're the only one complaining (or else you would have gone to your manager already and not to some webforum to ask this question to nameless randos if this was a problem that could be handled internally), it seems everyone else at the office (or at least the majority) appreciates this atmosphere as well.

Put simply: If you fight this, the fight will not end well for you.  Accept that this is how this person acts, and that the company you work for accepts people who act in this way, or find another job.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plus side to getting involved. Probably everyone else notices as well but is staying out of it.

This sort of behaviour can be career limiting in many places. You could give him a heads up if you felt the need, but that has potential issues, so you're best just to try and ignore it.

Acting professional is true for almost everyone. There is an expected standard in many professions and locales that most people usually live up to but do not adhere to outside work. Communication in particular is important, I used to think people were idiots for randomly saying 8 when I talked to them.

Acting 'gangster' is also an act, in my locale it's not tolerated and people quickly stop talking like that except amongst their peer group.

Answer (score 0):

I see two relatively non-confrontational ways to deal with this situation.

- Repeat the message of a slang phrase with a more standard/classier formulation.
- Pretend you don't understand the slang phrase and ask him to clarify it. Keep doing this, even for slang phrases he already explained. Maybe he gets annoyed and starts using standard English (with you).

I don't think these two things will solve it immediately or totally, but maybe they will have some effect.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like any sort of formal communication that would discourage slang.  Even the examples given may just be a quirk of how they enunciate.